# Focusing on one element, changes other element's CSS

Tags: css

Let's have a look at this very simple code:

```
<div class="search-box">
    <input type="text" class="input-search">
</div>
```

What I'm trying to achieve?

When I'm in :focus on the `.input-search`, I want it to change the background-color of the whole  `.search-box`

I did try this but it seems to not work because I am probably selecting something wrong:

```
.input-search:focus{
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

However, I have no idea how to apply this same effect to the .search-box class.

Thanks for any help yall!

Comment: @InSync read **all** the duplicate and you will find `focus-within` as one answer there. (it's the third answer, you don't need to read a lot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS cannot traverse up the DOM, so `:focus` can only be used for styling the specifically focused element. There is however `:focus-within` ([MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within)) which will allow you to style a parent element containing a focused element.

```css
.search-box:focus-within {
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div class="search-box">
    <input type="text" class="input-search">
</div>
```